# Include sub-classes with generated Google Cloud Endpoint client library

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, objectify

I am currently working on an Android project that stores data using Google Datastore and is accessible via the Cloud Endpoints with the Objectify library. The objectify library does a decent job explaining polymorphism using the "@Subclass" annotation however the problem I'm having is that when I generate the client library for use in the Android code the sub-classes are not included. Is there a way to force the compiler to include these classes?

Here is a basic example of what I'm doing. Lets take the polymorphism example from the Objectify documentation:

```
@Entity
public class Animal {
    @Id Long id;
    String name;
}

@Subclass(index=true)
public class Mammal extends Animal {
    boolean longHair;
}

@Subclass(index=true)
public class Cat extends Mammal {
    boolean hypoallergenic;
}
```

It's worth mentioning that all three of these classes have been registered with "ObjectifyService.factory().register()." Using the classes above I have a method in my api that looks similar to this:

```
@ApiMethod(
            name = "getAnimals", path = "zoo/getAnimals", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET
)
public Collection<Animal> getAnimals(final User user, @Named("IdList") Collection<Long> idList)
        throws UnauthorizedException {
    // If the user is not logged in, throw an UnauthorizedException
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
    }

    Map<Long,Animal> animalMap = ofy().load().type(Animal.class).ids(idList);

    ArrayList<Animal> animals= new ArrayList<>();
    for (Long animalId:idList) {
        animals.add(animalMap.get(animalId));
    }
    return animals;
}
```

As you can see the final ArrayList "animals" could contain Animals, Mammals, or Cats however the generated library only gives me access to the Animal class. I need to make sure that the sub-classes are available to the Android code. How does the compiler know which classes to include and is there a way to force a class to be added? Does the polymorphism even carry over to the client side or is that only supported server side?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great answer but you could expose a no-op API which returns those types (in reality just return null;). This should force the class generation. If there's a more formal way to do this, feel free to correct me.

Comment: I did consider creating dummy calls to force the addition of the classes however this just screams bad practice and decided against it. I did change the original call to return only Cat objects just to test if that would add both mammal and animal classes. I found that the classes generated by the compiler do not include the polymorphism at all. The generated Cat class extended the GenericJson class which makes me think that this collection would not return the mixed objects I hoped for. I've switched gears to UI but when I test the original call I will share my results.

Comment: the approach i've taken is the following: have an interface on the frontend to represent your data, eg Animal, and a concrete impl AnimalImpl which you can generate from the backend endpoints json classes. Your Animal can form a hierarchy of interfaces and respective impls.  I like this a lot also because the json crap is mutable whereas you can make your frontend impls immutable and hold any extra behavior and data. On the whole the json stuff is just not robust enough for front-end architecture IMHO. Good luck and would be interested to see what you found out!